# Android IDE defaults to old code

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

This is a little bizarre, and even more troublesome since I am so new to the IDE.

Last night I noticed if I hit the RUN button, it always resets all my last code changes, and goes to a previous compile version.

I saw this bug reported before, and one suggested solution was to create a new project and compile from scratch. Tried that, but the Android IDE is doing the SAME thing again!

If I delete 10 lines, they are back the instant I hit the Run button in the IDE. Not sure what is going on here...

-- Update --
I created a new USER ACCOUNT on my Mac, and fresh re-intall. I run into the SAME issue with my project.

Booted my Mac into BootCamp and tried to run my project on Windows. No issues, works fine, I can do my edits fine without issue.

Now why is my Mac possessed? I am just stumped.

Comment: did you invalidate cache and restart a.studio

Comment: Crossed my fingers and gave it a shot... still no go.

Comment: whats the version that you have

Comment: The version I have now is 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem , To resolve this problem follow this step:

1. Go to folder where project file is kept.
   2.delete .gradle file
2. delete build folder
3. Go App folder and again found build folder, delete it also
4. Now run the project.

Comment: Dear GOD I am so baffled here now. That didn't work, so after rebooting I also removed the entire Android IDE app.. re-downloaded fresh. The SAME THING keeps happening! As soon as I hit run, the source-code defaults to my last edits and I can't get anywhere. Even if I hit the SAVE option, it doesn't seem to be saving? I don't get any confirmation if anything is getting saved or not. Everything was fine until last night...

Comment: Alright, further update to my nightmare. When I made a new simple HELLO WORLD project, that seems to be working and editing fine at the moment. But another project I am working on (despite my code is being saved), gets swapped out to older code the second I press the Play button and cradle starts to work....    Just stumped here.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!!

Keeping my fingers crossed. All this started with the recent updates, so I am not sure if 2.2.3 is to blame. But I decided to empty my TRASH folder, since on OSX spotlight still knows files are there, despite deleted. There were some older code folders in there which I had deleted from elsewhere.

After emptying out my trash-bin and re-importing all over again, things are working now.